# What is the difference between green and red MAC addresses in wavemon's scan list?

Tags: wifi

In `wavemon`, what does red vs. green mean for the MAC addresses in the scan list?

For example:

[image]

The `wavemon` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/wavemon.1.html) says:

> **Scan window (F3)**
>
> ... Each  entry  starts with the ESSID,
>                 followed by the colour-coded MAC address and the  signal/channel
>                information. A green/red MAC address indicates an (un-)encrypted
>                access point, the colour changes to yellow for non-access points ...

But from that I can't tell what the difference between red and green is, only red/green vs. yellow.

Comment: What you posted actually does explain the difference. One of the two means it's encrypted while the other means unencrypted. Whether that means green is unencrypted or encrypted I don't know.

Comment: @Bratchley I thought that at first, too, but it didn't match the security columns on the right. But then it just now occurred to me to look at the source and it turns out you're right, so either "(un-)encrypted" means something else, or I've misinterpreted the column on the right (maybe red with no entry in this column means WEP or something).

Answer (score 2):

It just occurred to me that I could look at [the source](https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon/blob/master/wavemon.c). In `wavemon.c` there are some color palette initialization lines:

```
init_pair(CP_SCAN_CRYPT,  COLOR_RED,    COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(CP_SCAN_UNENC,  COLOR_GREEN,  COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(CP_SCAN_NON_AP, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
```

I take this to mean that:

- Red is encrypted.
- Green is unencrypted.
- Yellow, also as documented, is a non-access point.

The slash vs. parens in the "green/red" to "(un-)encrypted" pairing was confusing to me, I guess.